# How to formally say : "I am yyy calling from xxx company, how can I help you ?"

Tags: grammar, usage, culture, formal

From a customer service standpoint , how to formally say : "I am yyy calling from xxx company, how can I help you ?".
1：“我是客服 yyy，从 xxx 公司 打过来的。请问有什么可以帮助您 ？”
2： “我叫 yyy , 从 xxx 公司给您打电话了。请问怎么能帮助您 ？”
Any corrections/improvements/ other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Say 你好 (Hello) first
- It sounds more formal to state what company you are from before stating your name. "我是 xxx 公司的客服 yyy" or "我是 xxx 公司的客服, 我的名字是 yyy"
- Since you are speaking with the customer on the phone, "打过来的" or "给您打电话了" is redundant. Just like you wouldn't need to say "I am talking to you in person" if you are face to face with the customer.
- Either 请问有什么可以帮助您 or 请问怎么能帮助您 is fine for "how may I help you?"
- add final particle (呢) to soften tone, express keenness
- *Say "请问有什么**我**可以帮助您呢?"  instead of "请问有什么可以帮助您呢?" to stress 'it is I who will help you'*

> "你好, 我是 xxx 公司的客服, 我的名字是 yyy, 请问有什么我可以帮助您呢?"
>
> or
>
> "你好, 我是 xxx 公司的客服 yyy, 请问有什么我可以帮助您呢?"

Comment: Since it's a customer service person, 您好 may be more polite.